# Multiple Cognito environments w/ Amplify for iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito

Has anyone been able to set up Amplify across multiple environments? There aren't very clear instructions. We're using it as an identity provider, and web seems easy enough because you just import a config json that gets passed into the Amplify configure call. However android and iOS, it looks like the SDK is looking for config files on it's own. If that is the case, how are you supposed to have different config files for different environments?

Comment: Please add some tag to make your question to reach. Are you asking for setting the environments like Debug-Release? Then yes in iOS we can set the multiple config files for different environment.

Answer (score 0):

Two (albeit similar) ways to support this

1. Create an in memory AmplifyConfiguration as outlined [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/issues/460#issuecomment-634904060)
2. Point the configuration at a specific file as outlined [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/issues/460#issuecomment-667242080) in the same issue thread

Which option  you choose will depend on how complicated your configuration is, as well as how you're managing environment splitting for other aspects of your app. Because my app uses quite a few Amplify features, I went with the `configurationFile` option, pointing to a different amplifyconfiguration.json file based on build environment.